# How to access model in carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I did this the way it's below, but it's returning "no text". How to access model properly in carrierwave?

## photo_uploader.rb

```
process :poster

def poster
 manipulate! format:"jpg" do |source|
  txt = Magick::Draw.new
  txt.pointsize = 20
  txt.gravity = Magick::SouthGravity
  txt.fill = "white"
  source.border(50, 50, "black").annotate(txt, 0, 0, 0, 0, "#{model.title}" )

 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the model this way. All the error means is that there is actually no text in the title field of model. If you check the params hash, you'll probably see

```
"my_model"=>{"title"=>"", "image"=> ...)
```

So you can should check for a non-blank title in the controller:

```
unless params[:title].blank?
    MyModel.create(params[:my_model])
end
```